Obtaining non-overlapping trades in kdb
I've a table t as
q)trades: ([]
    signalTime: 2024.01.05 2024.01.12 2024.01.19 2024.01.25 2024.02.02 2024.02.09 2024.02.16 2024.02.23 2024.03.01 2024.03.07;
    exitTime: 2024.01.25 2024.02.01 2024.02.08 2024.02.15 2024.02.22 2024.02.29 2024.03.07 2024.03.14 2024.03.21 2024.03.28
 );
signalTime exitTime
----------------------
2024.01.05 2024.01.25
2024.01.12 2024.02.01
2024.01.19 2024.02.08
2024.01.25 2024.02.15
2024.02.02 2024.02.22
2024.02.09 2024.02.29
2024.02.16 2024.03.07
2024.02.23 2024.03.14
2024.03.01 2024.03.21
2024.03.07 2024.03.28

I would like to only keep trades whose intervening dates (between signalTime and exitTime) do not overlap with those of any other trades (rows). Alternatively, there should be only one trade during any given date. The expected output should be
signalTime exitTime
----------------------
2024.01.05 2024.01.25
2024.02.02 2024.02.22
2024.02.23 2024.03.14

While I'm able to conceive a solution using a do loop, how do i achieve this in more efficient, idiomatic q?
Here's my feeble attempt at the solution using a do loop though it's not quite correct.
removeOverlappingTrades:{[t]
    n: count t;
    accept: n#0b;          
    accept[0]: 1b;         
    lastExitTime: t[`exitTime][0]; 
    do[n-1; {[t;lastExitTime;accept;x]
        i: x+1;  // Current index
        if[t[`signalTime][i] >= lastExitTime;
           accept[i]: 1b;
           lastExitTime: t[`exitTime][i];
          ];
    }[t;lastExitTime;accept] each til n-1];
    t where accept
 };


It's better if you also include pastable input to create your sample table. Also useful for you to share your the attempt at the code to help us understand the logic you are looking for. All the rows in your example output do overlap with the windows of at least one other row. Can you clarify your meaning of "durations do not overlap"

@rianoc yeah, my bad. Here's the clarification and the input table as suggested.

// Add a dummy row to ensure the first row gets selected
// Add a boolean `b` column to capture results
q)r:update b:0b from ([] signalTime:enlist -0Wd;exitTime:enlist -0Wd),trades
q)r
signalTime exitTime   b
-----------------------
-0W        -0W        0
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 0
2024.01.12 2024.02.01 0
2024.01.19 2024.02.08 0
2024.01.25 2024.02.15 0
2024.02.02 2024.02.22 0
2024.02.09 2024.02.29 0
2024.02.16 2024.03.07 0
2024.02.23 2024.03.14 0
2024.03.01 2024.03.21 0
2024.03.07 2024.03.28 0

//scan through the table
//capturing when a new trade has no overlap with the prevailing
q)r:{[x;y] $[y[`signalTime]>x[`exitTime];
            [y[`b]:1b;y]; //New window opens, keep y with 1b set
            [x[`b]:0b;x]] //No new window, keep x with 0b set
 } scan r
q)r
signalTime exitTime   b
-----------------------
-0W        -0W        0
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 1
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 0
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 0
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 0
2024.02.02 2024.02.22 1
2024.02.02 2024.02.22 0
2024.02.02 2024.02.22 0
2024.02.23 2024.03.14 1
2024.02.23 2024.03.14 0
2024.02.23 2024.03.14 0

//Filter only when new windows opened
q)select from r where b
signalTime exitTime   b
-----------------------
2024.01.05 2024.01.25 1
2024.02.02 2024.02.22 1
2024.02.23 2024.03.14 1


Thanks. It's close, but it's missing the trade for February: 2024.02.02 2024.02.22.

Those dates are totally overlapped by combination of the 2024.01.25 2024.02.15 and 2024.02.09 2024.02.29 rows before and after?

Yes that's true, but I'd like to disregard them and get one trade running (if possible) at each time. I hope that makes sense.

Answer updated using scan to get your desired result https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#scan
